# Web scaping selected href with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape a website, including this article with python/BeautifulSoup:
https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/20/byd-planning-model-3-like-800-volt-sedan-called-seal/

At the end of each article you always find the sources. In the case of the link above, this is:

[image: Source picture]

In some articles on this website only one source is given, but sometimes two or three different ones. So the code needs to consider that.

Ideally I want the following output format: "text (href)"

```
xchuxing.com (https://xchuxing.com/article/45850)
cnevpost.com (https://cnevpost.com/2022/02/18/byd-seal-set-to-become-new-tesla-model-3-challenger/)
```

Here is my first code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/20/byd-planning-model-3-like-800-volt-sedan-called-seal/'
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
article = soup.find()

source = [c for c in article.find('section', class_='content').find_all('a')]
for link in source[3:]:
        link.get('href')
print (link)
```

Output as of now:

```
<a href="https://cnevpost.com/2022/02/18/byd-seal-set-to-become-new-tesla-model-3-challenger/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">cnevpost.com</a>
[Finished in 345ms]
```

Comment: `link.get('href')` line effective does nothing - you retrieve the href and throw it away. Either store it/bind it to a name or print. You iterate over all links (a tags) and print the last one, not href

Answer (score 0):

I think the sources always is in the last paragraph of the article, so do as below to extract them :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/20/byd-planning-model-3-like-800-volt-sedan-called-seal/'
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


paragraphs = soup.find('section', class_='content').find_all('p')
# the sources in the last paragraph
sources = paragraphs[-1].find_all('a')
# put the sources name and link in a dict
sources_links = []
for source in sources:
    sources_links.append((source.text, source['href']))

for l in sources_links:
    print(l)

# write in csv
with open('electrive_scrape_source.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Source', 'Link'])
    csv_writer.writerows(sources_links)
```

Save the data to csv file

Comment: This is great. Question how do I write multiple entries in a csv? . Please see my follow-up question

Comment: i update it to save data to csv file @webscrapeartist

Comment: thank you so much. One last question: Is there a way to safe both results in 1 row and 1 cell (e.g. source.com (https://link), source2.com(https://link2...)?

Comment: I think it's not a good idea because the data must be under columns, if you want to separate the sources of any articles add a new column and out the article's name or link in it @webscrapeartist

Comment: But I need the data in a cell separated by a comma due to the fact that this is part of a larger web script (multiple articles). Any chance you can add that to the code snippet?

Comment: so you need just a column, I will not change the answer but I put the new code in https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5G6xk3NQsW/ . this answer is completed. @webscrapeartist